# a matrix $A\in M_n(F)$ is called cyclic.I want an example for this.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know a matrix $A\in M_n(F)$ is called cyclic if there is a vector $a \in M_{1\times n}(F)$ such that $\{α,αA,\ldots,αA^{n−1}\}$ is a basis for $M_{1\times n}(F)$ as a left vector space over F. I want  an example for cyclic matrix and vector $a$.   but I do't find any example. can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

What about $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x_1 \\ 1 & 0 & & \cdots & x_2 \\ 0 & 1 & \ddots & & \vdots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0 & x_{n-1} \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & x_n \end{pmatrix},$$ where the $x_i$ are in $\mathbb{C}$ ($x_1\neq 0$) and $a=(1,\underset{n-1\text{ times}}{\underbrace{0,...,0}})$ ?